# Is Android Gradle Plugin test apk builder automatically multidexing my test apk? If so, why is this generating "NoSuchMethodError"

Tags: android, android-proguard, android-multidex

This all started with this error when running instrumentation tests:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method closeQuietly(Ljava/net/ServerSocket;)V in class Lokhttp3/internal/Util; or its super classes (declaration of 'okhttp3.internal.Util' appears in /data/app/com.example-vKdPJoTLl49ntRbZfsRBqQ==/base.apk!classes2.dex)
at okhttp3.mockwebserver.MockWebServer$2.execute(MockWebServer.java:333)
at okhttp3.internal.NamedRunnable.run(NamedRunnable.java:32)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

I went looking into the generated test.apk to see what was present/missing in dex files.

First thing I noticed is that the test apk has two `.dex` files. Why? I'm not using multidex (and IIRC multidex doesn't work on test apks anyways). I then added up the two "referenced method counts" and sure enough I'm over the 65k limit. So is AGP auto-multi-dexing my test apk?

[image: classes.dex]
[image: classes2.dex]

Furthermore I see the "missing" method in the **first** dex.

Why is it listed as a "reference" not a "defined" method? It's not like there is an OkHttp `Util` class provided by the framework.

In the initial crash, it said it can't find method in `classes2.dex`. Why is it looking in classes2.dex? Why not look in both?

I'm keeping *everything* in my test apk (using proguard but keeping everything) (maybe this explains the +65k ref methods). So why is this getting stripped/screwed with in the first place.

UPDATE:

It turns out this method was needed in my app .apk (not the test .apk). When I updated my proguard rules for the app apk everything worked. I still don't know why this class is needed in-app?

Answer (score 0):

> **java.lang.NoSuchMethodError**:
>
> No static method `closeQuietly(java.net.ServerSocket`) in class `okhttp3.internal.Util`;

method `closeQuietly(java.net.ServerSocket)` might not be in use.

to explicitly keep it:

```
-keep class okhttp3.internal.Util {
    public static void closeQuietly(java.net.ServerSocket);
}
```

Comment: I don't understand. Doesn't the crash I'm seeing mean the method is used? If its not in use as you suggest, how would keeping them make a difference? Why would I keep all three overloads of the `closeQuietly` method?

Comment: @tir38 the constructor with the `ServerSocket` might not have been kept by `includedescriptorclasses` and that's why my example is a rule which should explicitly keep one more constructor.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how I didn't know this but apparently multidex is enabled by default on API 21+

https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex#mdex-on-l

> Therefore, if your minSdkVersion is 21 or higher multidex is enabled
>   by default, and you do not need the multidex support library.

So yeah, this is normal. What might be happening is that the class is just not in the first dex file.